# How to add BI features in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssis, sql-server-2014

I have to add BI features such as SSRS, SSAS, SSIS in my existing SQL Server 2014.  I already try to add BI for my SQL, I have download SSDTBI and installed on my system. But I am not able to connect any service such as SSRS, SSAS, SSIS in my SQL Server Management Studio 2014. Can you anyone assist or help me.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb500469%28v=sql.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I will try that link and let you know

Comment: Thank you Richards.